# Turn on 'Always-on vpn' feature android

Tags: android, kotlin, vpn

Im wonder if someone can help me with this.
i want to turn on 'Always-on vpn' feature programmatically in kotlin.
i appreciate that if someone can provide some codes or explain the process of implementing it.

Also i have a question about it, is it appropriate to implement vpn kill switch in this way or not?

Answer (score 2):

Summarising the following official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/vpn)

### 1. Create your VPN service using [`VpnService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService)

> Protect the service with the `BIND_VPN_SERVICE` permission so t**hat only the system can bind to your service**.

> **Advertise the service with the "android.net.VpnService"** intent filter so that the system can find your service.

Example declaring the service in the `manifest`

```
<service android:name=".MyVpnService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

### 2. Prepare and connect the service

> To prepare the app to become the user’s current VPN service, call **VpnService.prepare()**.

> If the person using the device hasn’t already given permission for your app, the method returns an activity intent. You use this intent to start a system activity that asks for permission. 
> **The system shows a dialog that’s similar to other permissions dialogs**, such as camera or contacts access. If your app is already prepared, the method returns `null`.

For the connection steps, I would suggest you to carefully read this documentation [section](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/vpn#connect_a_service), so you will be able to fully comprehend the service.

### 3. Start the service

> Your VPN service can be started in the following ways:
>  1. Your app starts the service—normally because a person tapped a connect button.
> 2. The system starts the service because always-on VPN is on.

> The system starts your service in the background by calling onStartCommand().
> **However, Android places restrictions on background apps in version 8.0 (API Level 26) or higher. If you support these API Levels, you need to transition your service to the foreground by calling Service.startForeground()**

### 4. Stop the service

For the stopping steps please follow this [section](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/vpn#stopping_a_service) reading carefully to understand how and when the service has to stop / died.

### Always-on

The steps to implement the Always-on feature are not far away from the steps above. Use this [section](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/vpn#always-on) to learn more, and you can also use this [project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn) to help you out. The project is in Java, not Kotlin, but it could help give you a general idea on how to implement it in your app.

***EDIT***

To implement the Always-on feature you can use this [project](https://github.com/zaneschepke/wgtunnel) from
Github! It's fully Kotlin and the last update was 1 hour ago (at the time of writing this). You can find the `ForegroundService.kt` [here](https://github.com/zaneschepke/wgtunnel/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/zaneschepke/wireguardautotunnel/service/foreground/ForegroundService.kt) and the `manifest` [here](https://github.com/zaneschepke/wgtunnel/blob/main/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented connect & disconnect process and it work correctly. I just need Always-on feature to be turned on programmatically.
I checked the project you mentioned , but it seems to not support Always-on feature programmatically. Also i have read the official document about it but it didn't provide any code to turn it on in code.

Comment: @NavidShokoufeh I updated the answer linking an updated Kotiln project from GitHub using the Always-on feature.